# How can I turn off blue line when i close function in vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfEYk.png

Hello I want to ask how can i remove showing blue line when i close function in vs code. I can't find it anywhere. I hope someone knows and will help me solve my problem.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to turn off the option "Folding Highlight" in settings.  Search "highlight" and it should show up in the list.  Simply uncheck the option.

[image: Highlight setting]